# Router slowing down to a crawl

Tags: networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt, speed

Recently I upgraded my 2Mbps ADSL connection to a 6Mbps ADSL2+. Ever since this has been happening:

After a router reset, the connection from modem to router is at a speed of 6Mbps for around 15 minutes, after that, I wouldn't get anything over 0.6Mbps.

The connection from modem to a PC is at a speed of 6Mbps all the time.

I use a LinkSys e1200v2, this started happening after the modem update; but there's no reason to blame the modem since direct connection (from modem to PC) is just fine, so I rebooted the router, again, good connection for 15 minutes, then the same problem happens again (connection speed drops to 0.6 Mbps).

Then I changed the router's firmware to DD-WRT with the same problem, used another cheap Nexxt router with DD-WRT and got the same Problem.

Some other things I've tried:

1. Changed MTU size.
2. Disabled QoS.
3. Disabled Firewall.
4. Set static DHCP.
5. 30-30-30 reset.
6. Physically removed the router away from possible electrostatic interference.

Note: my router handles my public I.P.
This problem happens to both wireless and wired connection.

Comment: How are you measuring the speed of the connection from the modem to the router?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer; I am using SpeedTest.net...

Comment: Check for a missing DSL filter. Every device connected to your phone line (except the modem/router) must have a proper DSL filter. It's easy to miss things like alarm systems, satellite receivers, and so on.